# Does being untargetable prevent all effects?

Tags: league-of-legends

Being untargetable (Yi's Alpha Strike, Fizz's Playful/Trickster, Fiora's ult, etc.) prevents lots of bad things from happening to you, but does it stop everything such as:

1. AoE effects

   - Nunu's ult (damage and/or slow?)
   - Morgana's ultimate (if untargetable, can she not start cast at all, or if already on, will it "break" the leashes?)
2. DoT ticks

   - Ignite
   - Morde's ult
   - the end of Vlad's ult
3. Global spells

   - Karthus's Requiem (ult)
   - Twisted Fate's Destiny (ult)

Does "untargetable" mean literally that, that no targeted spells ("click-targeted" spells, skill-shots, or targeted AoEs work) land but non-targeted (point-blank AoE, global) do?  (But still, what about DoTs...)

Answer (score 3):

Untargetable refers to champions in a state where targeted spells cannot be cast on the untargetable champion, and nontargeted spells such as Karthus's  Requiem will have no effect.  Additionally, they cannot be targeted by auto attacks.

A more comprehensive list of Invulnerability:

**Complete Invulnerability**

> These break all forms of leashes and makes the champion invulnerable to all damage.
>
> - Shaco's Hallucinate makes him untargetable for a short time before the clone spawns.
> - Zhonya's Hourglass's active ability makes your champion untargetable for two seconds.

**Partial Invulnerability**

> Projectiles fired before the untargetability starts will have no effect. They will still take damage from DoTs such as Ignite and Malzahar's Malefic Visions and will not break leashes such as Fiddlesticks's Drain and Morgana's Soul Shackles. They will still be damaged by Zilean's Time Bomb, but not Fizz's Chum the Waters.
>
> - Fizz's Playful makes him untargetable for 0.75 seconds or until he uses Trickster.
> - Vladimir's Sanguine Pool makes him untargetable for 2 seconds.

**Dashes**

> Projectiles (autoattacks or abilities) that are mid-flight when the character starts dashing will hit when the dash completes. They still take damage from DoTs while untargetable.
>
> - Maokai's Twisted Advance makes him untargetable while moving to the target.
> - Master Yi's Alpha Strike makes him untargetable for a short time while in flight.
> - Fiora's Blade Waltz makes her untargetable for a short time while in flight.

source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Untargetable

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer is that any Damage Over Time spells (Ignite, Malzahar's Malific Visions) or Leash effect (Nocturn's Unspeakable Horror and Morgana's Soul Shackles) that is on a champion when they become untargetable will remain (with at-end-of-leash effects only occurring if the untargetability has ended by then).

EVERY other spell and ability will **not** affect the untargetable champion.

Answer (score 0):

Untargetable makes it so you can't be selected as a target for anything. However, if you are already a target for something, it will still be hitting you. For example, if Fiddlesticks uses Drain on you, it will still be hitting you. If someone auto-attacked and it connected while you were still untargetable, it'd still hit you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really hard question to answer in general, because different champions act differently, for example when Fiora use's her ultimate she can still take AoE damage, but cannot be targeted by spells. She will still receive the damage from active abilities on her like ignite and Morde's ult, etc. I believe it is the same case for Yi on these while using alpha strike as well. While with Fizz's playful trickster he is not effected by these ability AoE abilities, like Karthus ult, but if Morde ult's him before hand he still takes damage from it, I am unsure if he is able to break Morgana's ult when he uses playful trickster though.

These would be great question to submit to butbutbutILY for his current project Rift Myths.

Hope this answers some of your questions, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

1- the nunu i know for a fact he can dodge right at the end or possibly flip out only being slowed/damaged if he lands still in ult.

for morgana i know it will break leash but if others are in range and he lands back in leash range and finishes cast it will rebind.

2- for dots if he is lit up with ignites and so on before going into playful trickster he is still capable of dying for the duration of the dot it does not cleanse current damage on him.

3- for karth ult he can dodge at last second stopping the ult from connecting

with tf he cannot stop his initial global unless he has ESP in all honesty he would have to be dodging something else prior to this to stop tf gaining sight on him.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically simple. If something hits you as AoE damage it applies unless specific to complete invulnerability. Untargetable is literally what it is, untargetable. Champions and players cannot be targeted by anything including skillshots or selective spells. Certain cases AoE affects champions however it depends on the champion and type of untargetability.
Spells causing damage will continue to attack you but I'm unsure whether the damage continues during untargetability, however it is not necessary to break unless its a ability that only affects champions and you becoming untargetable cancels the enemy cast.

Comment: An answer has already been given to this question. Make sure you provide additional information instead of doubling up. Besides that, you have some assumptions in your questions. You should back those up with sources!